# Pywinauto app = Application.start() is not working and giving error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywinauto

I get an error when I try to start an exe file with pywinauto. This is my code:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application()
app.Start("D:\dragonboy160\dragonboy160.exe")
```

As far as I know that should work. `app = Application().start("")` does not work either. I also tried setting the imports like this: `from pywinauto import Application` I get this error when I run the python file in PyCharm:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\python.exe" D:/dragonboy160/screenview.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/dragonboy160/screenview.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pywinauto
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import findwindows
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import controls
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from . import uiawrapper # register "uia" back-end (at the end of uiawrapper module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\uiawrapper.py", line 44, in <module>
    from ..uia_defines import IUIA
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\uia_defines.py", line 35, in <module>
    import comtypes.client
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    gen_dir = _find_gen_dir()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\_code_cache.py", line 71, in _find_gen_dir
    result = os.path.abspath(gen_path[-1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I searched and searched and it seems no other person has had this problem. I also tried opening other .exe files but got the same error. What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try `app.Start("D:\\dragonboy160\\dragonboy160.exe")`

Comment: I tried that and I get the same result

Comment: `r'"D:\dragonboy160\dragonboy160.exe"`?

Comment: chet-the-wizard, that does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an import problem (at the very first line).

This looks like `comtypes` can't write cached files to `Program files` without admin privileges. In theory it might be fixed on comtypes side (or by re-installing Python to another folder like `C:\Python3x`), but **you will have to run the script as Administrator anyway** because of other OS restrictions (pywinauto will warn about insufficient rights in nearest future, now it's silent).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I managed to have it fixed by disabling `UAC` from Windows.

Comment: Disabling UAC shouldn't be an acceptable answer for end users.